# Own help message using optparse

Tags: python, optparse

is possible to make own help message or attach own event on help option using optparse module in Python?

Comment: What do you need that isn't explained clearly here:
http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html
You could try adding a newline and lots of help text in the usage parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace the default help mechanism with your own merely by subclassing `OptionParser` and overriding the [`print_help()`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#generating-help) method.

Comment: I'm curious as to how this is the accepted response when it is way over-engineered in the way you would do it. There's no need to do this at all as there is already a method on the class to do this.

Comment: @Lee, I believe you misinterpreted the request.  Your approach will replace only the "usage" text, but the output to the help option will still display the formatted text showing all the options, defaults, etc.  It appears the OP wanted to replace *all* the output and overriding may be the best way to do that.

Comment: @Lee, you solution also doesn't strip `Usage: ` prefix from the output, so you've downvoted wrongly. =)

Answer (score 5):

Sure - just use the params to the OptionParser constructor:

```
import optparse

help_text = """
Hi, this is a really long help message for %prog. 

It's a pretty ace thing. (C)2010 Stuff etc.
"""
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=help_text, version="%prog 1.0 beta")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Did you mean to use description instead of usage?

Comment: Both are very similar but either works. The only difference is description won't overwrite the 'usage' line. At least, from what I can tell. 'description' also removes all new lines.

Comment: Given that this does not eliminate the automatic output of all the options, I'm not sure it actually addresses the request fully.

Comment: You can use callback inside optparse.OptionParser function to call your function

Comment: This prints "Usage: Hi, this is a...", which is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

For custom help messages I ignore [optparse](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/optparse.py) altogether:

```
import os
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser

__version__ = '1.0'    

progname = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
usage = """\
usage: %s [options] URL

options:
  --pprint     (default)
  -h --help
  --version
""" % progname

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or "-h" in sys.argv or "--help" in sys.argv:
        sys.exit(usage)
    if "--version" in sys.argv:
        sys.exit(progname + " " + __version__)

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--pprint", action='store_true', default=True)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    print(options, args)
```